# Android calling a network operation continuously?

Tags: android, multithreading, wait

In my android application I have to call a network operation after every 30 sec.

Now i call the below code from the onresume of an activity.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while(true){
                try {
                    HTTPConnection httpConnection = new HTTPConnection();
                    httpConnection.extendSession(userId);
                    wait(30000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

but it causes the following exception

```
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before wait().
```

How can I implement the above functionality?

Comment: Why calling wait when you can just use a Handler with PostDelay

Comment: instead of wait(30000) try Thread.sleep(30000)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a Timer/TimerTask in your case. The Timer runs on a differnt thread, and you schedule it a fixed interval of time. E.g.

```
class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
  public void run() {
     HTTPConnection httpConnection = new HTTPConnection();
     httpConnection.extendSession(userId);
  }
}
```

and onCreate

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTimerTask(), new Date(), 30000);
```

About your exception

`wait()` needs a `synchronized` block and a lock object. The common usage goes through the pair `wait()`/`notify()`, and since they are usually used called on different treads, you need a `synchronized` block to guarantee the correct access to the lock itself.

```
public static final Object mLock = new Object();

new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          synchronized(mLock) {
            while(true){
                try {
                    HTTPConnection httpConnection = new HTTPConnection();
                    httpConnection.extendSession(userId);
                    mLock.wait(30000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
          }
        }
    }).start();
```